# How to implement multiple highlight line sliders in line chart

Tags: android, charts, slider, mpandroidchart, shinobi

I want to implement single and multiple highlight line sliders in line chart. I am able to get only single highlight line slider with MPAndroidChart (https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) library. But I also need two highlight line sliders to allow the user to select range of values(min and max values) on the chart. Please refer the below image for more information:

[image: Desired Line Chart with multiple highlight line sliders]

Can we achieve the above requirement with any library or we need to draw a custom view?
Any help or guidance will be well appreciated.

Comment: have you found the answer?

Answer (score 1):

In terms of **shinobicharts**, while the Crosshair could be easily customised to act like one of sliders, in order to have the two sliders you'd probably want to make use of the Annotations feature.

You can create Annotations with custom Views and add them at any X, Y point (in data terms). You can also convert between data values and pixel values via the Axes. It is therefore possible to make the Annotation follow the user's finger as they drag across the screen.

The trickiest part would be placing the circle on the LineSeries at the right Y-value. As I mentioned above you can convert pixel values (e.g. from a user gesture) to data values so you could easily get the X value but the API would leave quite a bit of work up to you in order to get the correct Y value.

This kind of feature is something that is requested quite often and is certainly something we are looking at providing in the future but for now, while possible, it isn't available out-of-the-box.

*Disclaimer: I work for **shinobicontrols***