# Custom line slider in MPAndroidChart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I have been trying to include a line slider at the bottom of my real-time plotting data graph. I searched around in StackOverflow and googled a lot regarding this. I tried manually adding a seekbar and trying to highlight the thumb's x index, but it wasn't working and moreover I need something like scroll bar. 
The closest on SO I could find was [Creating a line slider on a graph in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29743092/creating-a-line-slider-on-a-graph-in-android) and [How to implement multiple highlight line sliders in line chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31423436/how-to-implement-multiple-highlight-line-sliders-in-line-chart/31512348#31512348) . I basically need an additional  vertical line slider that on sliding would highlight the point it intersects in the graph. Something like this.

[image: chart]

[The line slider is on the right] 
Can someone tell me how I can implement this?

Comment: Any solution on this?